# Repeated attempts at question vandalism, what's going on here, and what do we do?

Tags: discussion

I've personally rejected at least 3 attempts at vandalizing a specific question - "[is there a plugin for photoshop that lets me write right to left text](https://superuser.com/questions/20187/is-there-a-plugin-for-photoshop-that-lets-me-write-right-to-left-text)" , for example [this](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/11817).

What's the proper way to handle it? I've made sure people are aware of it through chat and here. What else could we do? Hopefully common sense would result in these edits being rejected, and/or rolled back even if it did, but is there anything else we can do?

Comment: I've also rejected at least two today.

Comment: Good thing those spammers have absolutely no clue how suggested edits work.

Comment: The question appears to not exist any longer (according to link result).

Comment: ya, its been deleted. I really posted this so people wouldn't approve those edits by accident, and cause i find such anomalies amusing.

Answer (score 8):

Treat them as spam bots, there's nothing much to do except reject the edits. [Too many rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/133693) will result in user not being able to suggest an edit, so that should alleviate the problem.

Catching anon spam bots is hard and severe penalties(such as IP bans) don't really help regular users. Best is to keep rejecting them.

Answer (score 8):

I've [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135131/prevent-suggested-edits-under-10-reputation-on-protected-questions) that suggested edits not be available to users under 10 reputation on protected questions such as this one. Targeted questions such as this one  could then be protected to prevent this kind of spam.

This question is already protected but, at the moment, that only stops new answers.